# What things should I use to beat the wall of flesh

Tags: terraria

So I am op at getting meteorite, heckstone(sry won't use bad words), stuff from floating islands, obsidian and stuff from the underworld, bad at non sticky explosives. Have arms dealer, demolitionist and no other attack-based npcs, what do I get 4 battle? Tell me where to get the guns, make the guns, where to get npcs if needed, and what materials needed for potions, explosives, how to make bunny cannon(if needed) and requirements/materials for armor. Give me any good and special tips if you could plz. Really want the hollow. Playing on mobile.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of effectively defeating wall of flesh

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, you should clarify why you think the answers in the linked question do not help.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the dark lance, the phoenix blaster, and night's edge. You get the Dark Lance from shadow chests in the underworld. You can open shadow chests with a shadow key found in dungeons. (Note, you can use shadow keys forever so there's no need to get more than one, just in case you didn't know), you can make the phoenix blaster by finding the Handgun in the dungeon and mixing that with some Hellstone bars and you create the night's edge by mixing the light's bane/blood butcher, Muramasa, the Blade of grass, and the Fiery Greatsword in a demon alter. Some potions I world recommend are Iron skin, Healing(Not Lesser), Obsidian skin, Water walking, Feather Falling, and Regeneration potions. also, if you want, you can use the minishark from the arms dealer and grenades from the demolitionist (or dynamite if you feel like you can use them with caution.)